# React styled-components: refer to other components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

According to [styled-components doc's](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) I can refer to another component to trigger, for example, a hover effect.

```
const Link = styled.a`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: papayawhip;
    color: palevioletred;
`;

const Link2 = styled.a`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: steelblue;
    color: white;

    ${Link}:hover & {
        background-color: greenyellow;
        color: black;
    }
`;

class Hello extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Link>Hello World</Link>
        <Link2>Hello Again</Link2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically, hovering mouse on my `<Link>` should trigger a change in `background-color` in `<Link2>`.

This is not happening. Any ideas why?

I prepared a code snippet here: https://codesandbox.io/s/qv34lox494

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can refer to styled-components which are children of your styled-component, not side-by-side.

See a quote from the doc:

> Here, our Icon component defines its response to its **parent** Link being
>   hovered

For your problem, you can create a wrapper for both of your links, and use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) in CSS like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    & ${Link}:hover + ${Link2} {
        background-color: greenyellow;
        color: black;
    }
`;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mo7kny3lmx

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to modify your selector on Link2 to use siblings (now it's nested item selector). In that case you can get rid of extra wrapper

```
    const Link = styled.a`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: papayawhip;
    color: palevioletred;
`;

const Link2 = styled.a`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: steelblue;
    color: white;

    ${Link}:hover + & {
        background-color: greenyellow;
        color: black;
    }
`;

class Hello extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Link>Hello World</Link>
        <Link2>Hello Again</Link2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. it works for many components:

```
const Hi0 = styled.div`
width:75px;
height:75px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
background: papayawhip;
color: palevioletred;
border-radius:50%;
`;
const Hi1 = styled.div`
width:75px;
height:75px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
background: papayawhip;
color: palevioletred;
border-radius:50%;
`;
const Hi2 = styled.div`
width:75px;
height:75px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
background: papayawhip;
color: palevioletred;
border-radius:50%;
`;

const Ind = styled.div`
width:75px;
height:75px;
border-radius:50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
background: steelblue;
color: white;
transition:0.5s;

`;

 const Wrapper = styled.div`
 ${Hi0}:hover  ~ ${Ind} {
 background: blue;

 };
 ${Hi1}:hover  ~ ${Ind} {

 background: red;
 };
 ${Hi2}:hover  ~ ${Ind} {

 background: yellow;
 };


`;
class App extends React.Component{
render() {
 return(
        <Wrapper>
    <Hi0>Hello World</Hi0>
    <Hi1>Hello World</Hi1>
    <Hi2>Hello World</Hi2>
    <Ind>Hello Again</Ind>
        </Wrapper>
 )
}
}

 export default App;
```

[sandboxexemple](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-https-09oyn2?file=/src/App.js)